# how to convert 2016-02-10 into 10 Feb, 2016 in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using the CakePHP 3 in my project and getting the date in my view as:

```
[start_date_time] => Cake\I18n\Time Object
                (
                    [time] => 2016-02-01T01:00:00+00:00
                    [timezone] => UTC
                    [fixedNowTime] => 
                )
```

I need to show the date in my view as 1 Feb, 2016 .

How can convert the date format in CakePHP 3?

Comment: Have you read [the Documentation about Time Helpers?](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/time.html#using-the-helper) Alternatively you can use [this helper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html) in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything from CakePHP to do this, PHP's [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/datetime) class provides all the tools necessary:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat(
    DateTime::ATOM,
    '2016-02-01T01:00:00+00:00')->format('j, M Y')
); // outputs "1, Feb 2016"
```

Comment: Since the OP is already working with a CakePHP time object (most probably coming from the ORM) which in the end wraps around PHPs `DateTime/Immutable` class, it makes sense to stick with that, and use the tools provided by the framework. There's also global configuration options for date/time output. Breaking out into pure core PHP does more harm than good here.

Comment: I disagree - you shouldn't default to using a framework's feature if it is already made available by the language's standard library. Locking yourself into framework-specific code is the real harm, or at best a trade-off. With no context given by the OP, there's no value to be gained from such trade-offs.